# Passport choice for travel to states of the former Yugoslavia

Tags: croatia, serbia, montenegro, kosovo

Long, long ago, I visited Yugoslavia (as it was at the time).  I would like to see it again and an attractive idea is to visit all of the successor states.  Is a night or two in each capital with travel between them by bus or train feasible?  At a guess, it would not be currently advisable to travel directly between Serbia and Kosovo but could I easily visit both if I entered via a third country.

A couple of successor states are now EU so I expect that I will have no problems visiting them.  Can I make a visa free short visit to all of the others?

I am a dual British / Irish (hence EU) citizen.  I expect that my Irish passport would be preferable for this trip.  Or would it be a good idea to carry both so I could use a different one for Serbia and Kosovo?

Comment: I always carry both passports, but then I can't use one of them to enter the other country (which is the US), so your motivation to do so may be less.  But I always advise people to consider the possibility of an emergency arising requiring them to change their travel plans.

Comment: @phoog I fluctuate on whether to carry both passports.  Often in areas where it might be desirable, it might also be suspicious.  E.g. crossing land borders far from home, it might look odd to try to enter one country with no exit stamp from the other, how did you get here?  Hence when would I change.  However, this is not so far from home and some of the countries are EU and so would not even stamp my Irish passport.   I could even use my passport card rather than the book for these countries.

Comment: My point is that I carry them both even if I don't plan to use them both, because an emergency might arise where I need to change my plans.  You can also use your passport card in the non-EU parts of former Yugoslavia.

Comment: Using any EU ID card (including the Irish Passport card) would avoid any trace of your travel route. This is important for any travel to Serbia. Any trace of entering Kosovo (i.e. Kosovo entry/exit stamp) from outside of Serbia can cause problems.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, I would use the passport card whenever possible for that reason.  I would also carry both books to provide more options.

Comment: Carrying both passports in the former Yugoslavia is absolutely no legal problem, but it also brings no tangible benefits. Whether or not it can help at all is a "what if" question. If you lose one of them, yes, it can help a lot if you have the other one with you. But if you get robbed or forget your bag somewhere, you'll most likely lose both of them and you'll face additional overhead of having to get both passports revoked and reissued (even though just one emergency travel document will be needed to get home).

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Losing both is indeed a concern.  The Irish passport card is attractive for this reason.  Because it is small, there are more choices on where to carry it e.g. my wallet.  So, if I lose just one item, just bag or just wallet, then I will still have the other.  Of course, I could be robbed of all of my possessions but I hope that is much less likely than a pickpocket or bag snatcher

Answer (score 5):

Certainly it's preferable to use your Irish passport in Slovenia and Croatia, but if you're not coming up against the 90/180 limit on your UK passport then there's no particular reason to avoid using it, either.  In addition to those countries, I've been in Bosnia a lot, and I doubt that you would find much difference using your Irish or UK passport.  I suppose the same is true of the other parts of the former Yugoslavia, but I have no experience in those places.  Certainly, none of them requires a visa of short-term visitors who are traveling with either passport:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Irish_citizens

Comment: My main current concern is situation in Serbia and Kosovo.  I am not super nervous but I thought it worth inquiring before going.

Comment: @badjohn i believe there are some other questions on the site about travel between Serbia and Kosovo.

Comment: I see other questions but they are old.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good site (for Croatia anyway) to find buses, trains and ferries:
[https://www.putovnica.net](https://www.putovnica.net/en)
Generally Croatia and Slovenia are easily traveled by public traffic, I just don't know about the other countries.

As for crossing between Kosovo and Serbia, you could cross from Montenegro. I did not find any buses on the site above, but maybe there is a better place to look for local buses or maybe there are no buses and you'll have to get a cab.