# Travel between successor nations of the former Yugoslavia

Tags: croatia, serbia, slovenia, bosnia, kosovo

I would like to tour all of the successor countries of the former Yugoslavia at a moderate budget.
How easy is it to travel by land between them?

Croatia and Slovenia are now in the EU so I expect that travel to and from them and between them is easy and safe.  I would probably use one of these as a base with excursions to the others.

I expect that travel directly between Serbia and Kosovo is impossible or inadvisable.  However, could I easily get to these countries from one of the others?

How about the remaining countries?  Is it easy to travel between these countries?

A little more detail.  I would like to avoid very expensive options e.g. a long distance taxi or a private driver.  Other suggestions are welcome e.g. cheap local bus, more up market buses, or trains.  It can be basic and rough (I am used to that) but it does not need to be.

Note that this question is not about passports.  That has been addressed in a different question: [Passport choice for travel to states of the former Yugoslavia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178489/passport-choice-for-travel-to-states-of-the-former-yugoslavia).

Comment: I suggest picking a starting country (let us choose Croatia since you mention it), find the appropriate page on the Man in Seat 61 site (https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Zagreb.htm) and then start from there.

Comment: Intercity buses are, at least in my somewhat limited experience, basic and rough, but they are generally reliable and are the primary means of intercity transportation, at least where trains are lacking, which is everywhere I've been.  I would certainly take a train where it was available, but the bus is likely to be best in most cases.

Comment: Maybe not that interesting as you might not do this. If you rent a car in Serbia, your car isn't insured in Kosovo. You can drive over the boarder into Kosovo but you'll need to buy an insurance before you can leave Kosovo. (Source: experience)
Rental companies might not ask your intentions.

Comment: @JorenVandamme I have no plans to rent a car.

Comment: @JorenVandamme Thanks, I'd be interested to learn more: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178710/1810

Answer (score 5):

This is quite a broad question, so I'll only attempt a general answer. Of course, the public transport level in the countries of former Yugoslavia is well below that of Western Europe (but that's part of the region's charm, isn't it?). Railway infrastructure is underdeveloped and cross-border trains are mostly non-existent, because many cross-border links have been damaged in the 1990s wars or fell into disrepair and haven't been rebuilt yet. AFAIK, the only possible cross-country connections are Slovenia - Croatia, Serbia - Kosovo, Serbia - Montenegro and Serbia - North Macedonia. None of them is faster than taking a bus, in fact, most of them are a lot slower. The Belgrade (Serbia) to Bar (Montenegro) route is nonetheless great for railfans, possibly the best one in the Balkans!

Inter-city buses (both domestic and international services) do exist everywhere in the Balkans, but the timetables could be sparse. Naturally, bus connections will be easiest to find when moving between big cities (such as country capitals). Plus, there's no single point of reference, so it requires some research. You can search sites such as Wikivoyage for links to bus companies or aggregator sites.

> I expect that travel directly between Serbia and Kosovo is impossible or inadvisable.

Quite the contrary. As of now, the border is open and there are reportedly scheduled bus and even train services crossing it several times a day. However, unexpected roadblocks or temporary closures of the border checkpoints still do occur every now and then.

The biggest problem is that Serbia does not admit 3rd party nationals who are entering from Kosovo if their passport bears evidence (stamps) of having first entered Kosovo from outside of Serbia (i.e. from Albania, Montenegro or North Macedonia). Travellers who can enter Serbia with their ID card (including an Irish passport card) need not to worry, because an ID card has no stamps. Another option is to adjust your itinerary.

Comment: Thanks.  I discovered some of that, e.g. crossing from Serbia to Kosovo, from the UK government site.  I will probably attempt this in my old backpacking style of making it up as I go.  Plan only as far as Croatia and then see how it goes.

Comment: There was a train from Sarajevo to Ploče between July 1st and September 11th last year, billed as "seasonal," so it might return next summer.  The scheduled time was a bit less than three and a half hours; I don't know how long the bus takes, but I doubt it could be much faster.

Comment: I have crossed the region by train myself.  Venice to Belgrade and Belgrade to Sofia.  However, that was so long ago that it was still Yugoslavia.  This is partly why I want to go: to see how different it is today.

Comment: @badjohn Not possible now. Both main railway tracks from the EU (from Croatia and from Hungary)  into Belgrade are out of service. The one from Hungary is being reconstructed and will definitely open at some point. The one from Croatia appears to be closed indefinitely, AFAIK there are no firm plans to reopen it.