# How can get I car insurance for a car that I plan to rent in Dubrovnik, Croatia and drive to the nearby Balkan countries?

Tags: car-rentals, croatia, albania, macedonia, bosnia

I may be in Dubrovnik, Croatia this May.  I plan to rent a car in Dubrovnik (or somewhere easy to reach from Dubrovnik) and travel to the nearby Bosnia and Herzegovina, Serbia, Kosovo, North Macedonia and Albania. How can get I car insurance for a car that I plan to rent in Dubrovnik, Croatia and drive to the nearby Balkan countries? Do car rentals typically include car insurance covering these nearby countries? If not, where can I get it?

Related: [Travel between successor nations of the former Yugoslavia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178667/1810), but the OP is not interested in car rentals.

Follow-up: [How is the land border crossing when driving a rented car between Balkan countries as a French citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178719/1810)

Comment: Why don't you just call a rental company and ask? I'm guessing Sixt , Europcar, and maybe Avis are your best shots.  Both Europcar and Sixt charge "cross border fees" so this is allowed in some case. How ever the written descriptions are so obtuse that it's probably easier just to call them up with your specific details

Comment: If the rental company allows you to drive the car across the border then their insurance will cover it. If they don't then it doesn't matter whether you can get insurance.