# If a French citizen enters Kosovo from Montenegro, Albania or North Macedonia using their French passport, will their passport show their Kosovo entry

Tags: passport-stamps, montenegro, albania, macedonia, kosovo

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/178695/1810):

> The biggest problem is that Serbia does not admit 3rd party nationals who are entering from Kosovo if their passport bears evidence (stamps) of having first entered Kosovo from outside of Serbia (i.e. from Albania, Montenegro or North Macedonia.

This makes me wonder: If a French citizen enters Kosovo from Montenegro, Albania or North Macedonia  using their French passport, will their passport bear evidence (e.g., stamps) of having entered Kosovo? If that depends on the mode of entry, I'm interest in entry by car, bus or foot.

Comment: Yes, see comment: [Passport choice for travel to states of the former Yugoslavia - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178489/passport-choice-for-travel-to-states-of-the-former-yugoslavia#comment450825_178489)

Comment: I've never been to Kosovo nor Serbia, so I can't say whether they'd stamp your passport, but Bosnia certainly stamps my EU passport in the airport, and I don't think they've ever stamped my EU or my non-EU passport at any land crossing. This may have been influenced by the fact that I was always in a car with some number of Bosnians.  Still, I'd say there's probably a realistic possibility of their not stamping your passport.  But why take the risk?  Use your ID card, or maybe work out some strategy of using your French passport in Kosovo and your US passport in Serbia, or vice versa.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the info! [Expired French ID](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178763/1810) + [waiting](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/23697/164) for US passport.

Comment: Yes, they'll see it, but will it matter? If you try to go from Albania to Kosovo to Serbia they will deny you entry. If you go Albania-Kosovo-Montenegro-Serbia they'll see it but won't care. If you want to go from Kosovo to Serbia you have to enter Serbia first. For example, you can go from North Macedonia to Serbia to Kosovo to Serbia.

Comment: @cbw got it, thanks! Just trying to prepare the route accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Serbian border officials will look at your passport and if they find a stamp from a border checkpoint between Kosovo and Albania / Montenegro / North Macedonia, they can refuse your entry into Serbia. The stamp can be either an entry stamp from Kosovo, or it can be an exit stamp from Albania / Montenegro / North Macedonia. Every passport stamp anywhere in the world displays the name of the border checkpoint (and sometimes also a mode of transport: road, rail, air, sea...). Serbian officials of course know the names of all Kosovo border checkpoints. They will see that you entered Kosovo from another country, which is a violation of a Serbian law.

I could go on and explain in great details things such as Balkan rule-bending mentality, probability of passing through a border checkpoint without getting any stamps to your passport, countries that do not stamp passports at all and instead use only computer databases to record arrivals and departures of foreigners, but it's not necessary.

My advice: leave your passport at home and take your plastic ID card only. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks. "Take your plastic ID card only" -> [Does Kosovo accept an national French ID whose expiry date on the card has passed, but in fact is not expired, for land entries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178763/1810). And my national French ID may be expired for good anyway when I try to enter Kosovo, I'm not sure yet, it depends on whether I enter Kosovo before or after my work meeting in Croatia, which I haven't decided yet. So more details are welcome :)

Comment: Tough question. :-) If you can't obtain a new ID card and your old one won't be accepted to enter Kosovo, you can still change your itinerary and visit Serbia first (using your passport). That's what I'd do, in your circumstances.