# Does Kosovo accept a national French ID whose expiry date on the card has passed, but in fact is not expired, for land entries?

Tags: borders, identity-cards, french-citizens, kosovo, expired

My French national ID card has an expiry date on the card in May 2018. However, France extended the validity of this card from 10 to 15 years, which means my French national ID card is valid till May 2023, even though the card itself states that the expiry date is in May 2018.

https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Duree-de-validite-de-la-CNI ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180804045811/https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Duree-de-validite-de-la-CNI)) contains a list of European countries that are supposed to accept or reject such a French ID card whose expiry date on the card has passed, but in fact is not expired. However, there is no mention of Kosovo.

Does Kosovo accept a national French ID whose expiry date on the card has passed, but in fact is not expired, for land entries?

I plan to enter Kosovo by land from Montenegro, Albania or North Macedonia.

Comment: Do you have time to replace the card before you travel? If so, I would, as it is only a few months and it will avoid problems. (I might or might not just after the end of the 10 years but I think at almost 15 years you have gotten your costs worth of it.)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, not really: I'm in the US and rather far from the nearest French embassy. I'll give a shot though. I wanted to replace it earlier to prepare for this exact case, but they refused because it wasn't near the official expiration and I had no confirmed travel then. Then Covid shut down the embassies.

Comment: If nothing else works, you can modify your itinerary to visit Serbia first, then Kosovo. Alternately, you can visit Kosovo first (as originally planned), hoping to get no stamps in your passport. It happens often in the former Yugoslavian countries (excluding Slovenia and Croatia) that the border guards just look at one's passport and hand it back. If this approach fails and your passport gets stamped, you can simply exit Kosovo to Montegro or North Macedonia and enter Serbia from there. It's a few more kilometers by car, not a big deal.

Comment: I can't decide if it's a good idea to ask the border guards not to stamp your passport when entering Kosovo. 1) it can work 2) they can ask for a bribe 3) they can subject you to intense scrutiny, checking all possible documents and parts of your car. Most likely not worth it.